# Marker Popup jQuery events no longer fire after re-opening Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have a Leaflet Popup attached to a Marker which is giving the user two buttons to cancel or move on to another page by using jQuery.

The buttons work fine initially except if you once click exactly on the marker so that the Popup disappears and then click on the marker again so that the Popup shows up again, then suddenly the buttons no longer work.

I do not get any error message in the browser console either.

What could be the issue?

```
var marker;

var addPopup = function(e, marker) {
    var popup = L.popup({closeButton:false})
    .setContent('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ok">Ok</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="nok">Cancel</button>');
    marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
    var Coordinates= JSON.stringify(e.latlng);
    popupAction(Coordinates, marker);
};

var popupAction= function(Coordinates, marker){
    $('#ok').on('click', function (){
      console.log('do something');  
    });
    $('#nok').on('click', function (){
        mymap.removeLayer(marker);
    });
};

mymap.on('click', function (e) {
    if (marker) {
        mymap.removeLayer(marker);
    }
    marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap);
    addPopup(e, marker);            
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a high chance your event listeners are lost on next popup opening. Leaflet probably recreates the popup content, hence your event listeners are no longer attached to this new content.

Therefore a workaround that comes to mind would be to re-execute your `popupAction` function (which attaches the event listeners on the popup buttons) on the marker's [`"popupopen"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layer-popupopen) event.

> Fired when a popup bound to this layer is opened

Unfortunately, doing so creates another bug, because when your user clicks somewhere else on the map while you already have a marker with its popup open, you remove the marker and create a new one, with a new popup content but with same buttons ID's. Therefore when jQuery tries to attach your listeners, it finds the previous buttons instead of the new ones. A new workaround would be to use something else than `id` as selector, so that jQuery can find the new buttons as well, e.g. classes.

A proper solution would simply be to use [*event delegation*](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), which is easy to implement with jQuery:

```js
var mymap = L.map("map");

var marker;

var addPopup = function(e, marker) {
  var popup = L.popup({
      closeButton: false
    })
    .setContent('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ok">Ok</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="nok">Cancel</button>');
  marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
};

// Use event delegation, so that buttons may be removed from DOM but event listeners will persist on parent container.
// http://api.jquery.com/on/
// https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
$('#map').on('click', '#ok', function() {
  console.log('do something');
}).on('click', '#nok', function() {
  mymap.removeLayer(marker);
});

mymap.on('click', function(e) {
  if (marker) {
    mymap.removeLayer(marker);
  }
  marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap);
  addPopup(e, marker);
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="pr5848.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot for this detailled explanation, problem solved!